# Why is this batch script crashing?

Tags: batch-file, winapi

This is a simple batch file for displaying a low battery notification.  The components of it have been drawn together from looking at other peoples' posts and tested.  I'm quite confused but I think I broke it when I was adding the 'hasBeenNotified' check.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
set multipleNotification=5
set BatteryLevel=-1
set notificationThreshold=20
set hasBatteryNotified=0
:: if on battery
wmic Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus | find "2" > nul
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (

    :: if battery level low, notify
    for /f %%a in ('wmic.exe path Win32_Battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining ^| findstr.exe /r "[0-9][0-9]*"') do set BatteryLevel=%%a
    set /a notMultiple = %BatteryLevel% %% %multipleNotification%
    if %BatteryLevel% leq %notificationThreshold% if %notMultiple%==0(

        :: if not notified
        if %hasBatteryNotified%==0(
            start cmd /K echo Batery is at %BatteryLevel%!!
            set hasBatteryNotified=1
        )
    ) else (
        set hasBatteryNotified=0
    )
) else (
    set hasBatteryNotified=0
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if %hasBatteryNotified%==0 (
```

and

```
if %BatteryLevel% leq %notificationThreshold% if %notMultiple%==0 (
```

there have to be spaces before the `(` (yes, Batch is very picky about spaces)

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to take care of it; but I've changed my code to comply and thanks for the response!

Comment: still crashing? Remove the `@echo off` and start it from `cmd` (not per double-click) to see any errormessages.

Comment: It says that getbatterystatus 2 was unexpected at this time.

Comment: That issue was because %errorlevel% has to get special treatment in an if statement